# Can we use Permanent ToolBar in Parallax Header ViewPager?

Tags: android, header, android-viewpager

I am having an issue of setting ToolBar(BLACK RECTANGLE) permanently in the Parallax Header ViewPager.

Default Layout is like this IMAGE 1 & I need as same as like this with Permanent ToolBar.

[image]   [image]

**I need to know that whether it is possible or not.**

Comment: See my updated answer, it has a layout

Answer (score 1):

Please post the layout file you are currently using.

There should be a way to do this.  You would have two toolbars in the CollapsingToolbarLayout.  One toolbar you specify as the collapsing toolbar using `app:toolbarId` on the collapsing toolbar.  On this toolbar you would set the home/back icon and the options menu.  A different toolbar should be the first child of the collapsing layout and have `app:layout_collapseMode="pin"`.  On this toolbar you would set the title and optionally subtitle.

Here's a layout I was playing around with, I had to take out `fitsSystemWindows` to make it look better.  Try it out:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.pinnedtoolbar.ScrollingActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:src="@drawable/abby"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/titleToolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_scrolling" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here's some of the code that went along with it:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scrolling);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        // erase the expanded title    
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(null);

        // set the title on the other pinned toolbar
        Toolbar titleToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.titleToolbar);
        titleToolbar.setTitle("This is the real title");

    }
```